# shuf generates "Bad file descriptor" error on nfs but only when run as a background process

Tags: nfs, gnu-coreutils

Here is an interesting mystery ...
This code ...

```
shuf $TRAINING_UNSHUFFLED > $TRAINING_SHUFFLED
wc -l $TRAINING_UNSHUFFLED
wc -l $TRAINING_SHUFFLED

shuf $VALIDATION_UNSHUFFLED > $VALIDATION_SHUFFLED
wc -l $VALIDATION_UNSHUFFLED
wc -l $VALIDATION_SHUFFLED
```

generates this error ...

```
shuf: read error: Bad file descriptor
8122 /nfs/digits/datasets/com-aosvapps-distracted-driving3/databases/TrainImagePathsAndLabels_AlpineTest1.csv
0 /nfs/digits/datasets/com-aosvapps-distracted-driving3/databases/TrainImagePathsAndLabels_AlpineTest1_Shuffled.csv

shuf: read error: Bad file descriptor
882 /nfs/digits/datasets/com-aosvapps-distracted-driving3/databases/ValImagePathsAndLabels_AlpineTest1.csv
0 /nfs/digits/datasets/com-aosvapps-distracted-driving3/databases/ValImagePathsAndLabels_AlpineTest1_Shuffled.csv
```

but ONLY when I run it as a background job like so ...

```
tf2$nohup ./shuffle.sh >> /tmp/shuffle.log 2>&1 0>&- &
[1] 6897
```

When I run it directly in an interactive shell, it seems to work fine.

```
tf2$./shuffle.sh > /tmp/shuffle.log
```

I am guessing that this has something to do with the fact that both the input and output files reside on an nfs share on a different aws ec2 instance.

The severing of stdin, stderr and stdin in the background process example is suspicious. This is done so that the process will not die if the terminal session is closed. I have many other commands that read and write from this share without any problems at all. Only the shuf command is being difficult.

I am curious as to what might be causing this and if it is fixable without seeking an alternative to shuf?

I am using shuf (GNU coreutils) 8.21 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

```
tf2$which shuf
/usr/bin/shuf

tf2$shuf --version
shuf (GNU coreutils) 8.21
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Paul Eggert.

tf2$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

**UPDATE: eliminating the severing of STDIN makes the problem go away**

ie. if instead of doing this ...

```
$nohup ./shuffle.sh > /tmp/shuffle.log 2>&1 0>&- &
```

I do this ...

```
$nohup ./shuffle.sh > /tmp/shuffle.log 2>&1 &
```

the "Bad descriptor" error goes away.

However, the severing of stdin/stdout/stderr is there to ensure that killing the terminal session will not kill the process, so this solution is not entirely satisfactory.

Furthermore, it only seems be be necessary to do this for shuf. None of other commands which read files from this file system cause any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in glibc.
The details are here:
https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25029

The work-around is simple:
instead of

```
shuf $TRAINING_UNSHUFFLED > $TRAINING_SHUFFLED
```

do

```
shuf < $TRAINING_UNSHUFFLED > $TRAINING_SHUFFLED
```

Thanks to Pádraig Brady on the coreutils team.